# Is there a way to explicitly state which Jenkins library file to use?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a pipeline which loads 2 shared libraries, say

```
@Libray(['sharedlib1@master', 'sharedlib2@trunk'])_
```

The problem is both pipelines have a file, say

> var/configuration/config.yaml

When I do something like `globalConfig = libraryResource 'var/configuration/config.yaml'`, how do I explicitly state that it should read from 'sharedlib2'?

The current syntax gives an '`ERROR: Library resource var/configuration/config.yaml ambiguous among libraries [sharedlib1, sharedlib2`]'

Answer (score 0):

The `libraryResource` step doesn't currently support specifying from which library the resource should be loaded if the same resource is present in multiple libraries.

I can see 2 ways to solve it:

1. Refactor the shared library resources files structure and put everything in a base directory with the library name

   ```
   sharedlib1/var/configuration/config.yaml
   sharedlib2/var/configuration/config.yaml
   ```

   Then, you could load the resource from the desired library using the library-specific path:
   `globalConfig = libraryResource('sharedlib2/var/configuration/config.yaml')`
2. use the library step to load the libraries explicitly and alias them, then use `@Library` to specify which one to use:

```
library('sharedlib1@master') _
library identifier: 'sharedlib2@trunk', retriever: modernSCM(
  [$class: 'GitSCMSource',
   remote: 'https://github.com/my-org/sharedlib2.git']),
  changelog: false, poll: false, _ 

@Library('sharedlib2') _
globalConfig = libraryResource('var/configuration/config.yaml')
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that Jenkins shared libraries need to have predictable folder structure and file names ([here's why](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-43724)), I'd simply put each shared library into a separate git branch within the same repository:

- branch `sharedlib1`:

```
/vars/sharedlib1.groovy
/resources/sharedlib1-script.sh
/resources/configuration/config.yaml
```

- branch `sharedlib2`:

```
/vars/sharedlib2.groovy
/resources/sharedlib2-script.sh
/resources/configuration/config.yaml
```

etc.

Then the files put in `/resources` can have the same names (between some or all branches).

Comment: Whilst this is a great solution, the problem is I can't merge the 2 libraries into the same repository due to different teams owning the same (but slightly different) code...ah the joys of working corporate...